# Uploading images in Django fails in production on digital ocean

Tags: python, django, django-models, debian, digital-ocean

I created my website and media was working fine, but now in production static files are okay but media files doesn't work. When making a new post by a user usually you would have to put a thumbnail and you also have the ability to use the text editor to add pics into your post using django-summernote. Anyways it should upload them to media root in the server but it doesn't. It just gives me 500 server error and in the editor it gives me

> Got an error uploading an image: Failed to save attachment

my urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and my settings.py

```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static-root/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
  # '/var/www/static/',
]
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/media-root/'
```

I've read that I might need to serve my media and static in another server 
why? Static works fine but media doesn't.

I'm using Debian for the Django code.

Comment: Check the user. You may not have permission to write `/var/www/media-root/`

Comment: DO NOT serve static or media files using static() other than locally while development. Configure the web server to serve `STATIC_ROOT ` and `MEDIA_ROOT ` directories.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov how do i do that , im kind of a beginner at this sorry and thanks in advance

Comment: @mdegis how do i do that ? you mean like chmod -R ug+rw /var/www/media-root ? i did that but it still gives me that 500 error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx you need to tell it where to find the /media/ files, so in your nginx configuration server file you need to add:

```
location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /var/www/media-root/;
}
```

Also, I prefer use just `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` to have the media files inside of my project folder. In your way you need to create the folder and give it permissions `mkdir /var/www/media-root` and `chmod -R ug+rw /var/www/media-root`

Comment: im using apache 2 not nginx and i used this Alias /media /var/www/media-root
<Directory /var/www/media-root>
   Require all granted
</Directory> but it still gives me the server error

Comment: i used a command similar but instead its chown -R www-data /var/www/media-root
 and it works now!!